# SVN, pre-revprop-change hook automatic creation

Tags: svn

I recently had a problem with a brand new SVN server: I couldn't insert anything in it. I found out that the "pre-revprop-change" file was missing. So I created it in the "hooks" subdir of every repo I made.

The point is that for each new repo I create I must manually add the file! Is there a way to automatically create the pre-revprop-change file when I create a new repository?

I use subversion on an Ubuntu server and USVN 1.0.7 to manage everything.

Comment: That wasn't the cause of your problem, unless there's something else you aren't including in your post. Hook scripts are **never** required in Subversion, unless you specifically need the functionality that the script would provide.

Comment: That solved the issue, that's all I know :(